# Not getting Latitude and Longitude in android

Tags: android, android-manifest, latitude-longitude

> I have searched on Google regarding this issue but didn't get the
>   solution.I am trying to get Longitude and Latitude of device location.
>   User will click the image from Camera and at that time I have to get
>   the Lat,Long of the device using GPS and display that. But is is not
>   working.

Here is my code:-

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText editAddress,editName;
    ImageView ivPhoto;
    Button btnTakePic,btnNext1;
    Bitmap bitMap;
    static int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;

    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    protected LocationListener locationListener;
    protected Context context;
    TextView txtLat;
    String lat;
    String provider;
    protected double latitude,longitude;
    protected boolean gps_enabled,network_enabled;

    private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // in Meters

    private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000; // in Milliseconds


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        editAddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtAddress);
        editName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtName);
        ivPhoto = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivPhoto);
        btnTakePic = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTakePic);
        btnNext1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNext1);


        btnTakePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent,TAKE_PICTURE);

            }
        });

        btnNext1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent nextIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ContactPersonDetail.class);
                startActivity(nextIntent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void GetLocationLatLong() {


        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

      //  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, new MyLocationListener());

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if(location!=null){


            String message = String.format("Current Location \\n Longitude: %1$s \\n Latitude: %2$s",location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode== RESULT_OK && intent != null){
            // get bundle
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

            // get bitmap
            bitMap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            ivPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitMap);

            GetLocationLatLong();

        }
    }

    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{



        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            String message = String.format("New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s", location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude() );

            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Log.d("Longittuteeeeeeeeeeee",message);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {




            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Provider status changed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Provider enabled by the user. GPS turned on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }


}
```

> These are the permissions used in manifest :-

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

> In these permission, two permissions (ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION,CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES) are giving error.
>
> errors in permission:-
>
> > uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"
>
> Mock locations should only be requested in a test or debug-specific
>   manifest file (typically src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml) less...
>   (Ctrl+F1)  Using a mock location provider (by requiring the permission
>   android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION) should only be done in debug
>   builds (or from tests). In Gradle projects, that means you should only
>   request this permission in a test or debug source set specific
>   manifest file.  To fix this, create a new manifest file in the debug
>   folder and move the  element there. A typical path to
>   a debug manifest override file in a Gradle project is
>   src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml.

Please let me know what I mistake I am doing here.

Comment: code that you are using is for getting lat long when there is a change in location but I don't think you need that. You can simply get latitude and longitude by following this link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/. You only need code related to getLatitude and getLongitude method

Answer (score 0):

This part of your GetLocationLatLong function must be in your onCreate method:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
   locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, new MyLocationListener());
```

You should set requestLocationUpdates before that method. The rest should work fine.

Also, you don't need these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES" />
```

Comment: Hello Brother, I tried what u have suggested but nothing is happening.:(

Comment: Use Logs to check if your onActivityResult method is being called and where. Also check if the method GetLocationLatLong is ever being called. The problem may be there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this. I'm currently using this one to get the device's current location.

```
public class GPSHelper {

private Context mContext;
// flag for GPS Status
private boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
// flag for network status
private boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private double latitude;
private double longitude;

public GPSHelper(Context context) {
    mContext = context;

    locationManager = (LocationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

}

public LatLng getMyLocation() {
    List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);

    Location l = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < providers.size(); i++) {
        l = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(providers.get(i));
        if (l != null)
            break;
    }
    if (l != null) {
        latitude = l.getLatitude();
        longitude = l.getLongitude();
    }

    return new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
}

public boolean isGPSenabled() {
    isGPSEnabled = locationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    // getting network status
    isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    return (isGPSEnabled || isNetworkEnabled);
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 */
public double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 */
public double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}
}
```

Usage:

```
GPSHelper gpsHelper = new GPSHelper(getActivity());//I'm creating this object inside a fragment
LatLng currentLatLng = gpsHelper.getMyLocation();
currentLat = currentLatLng.latitude;
currentLng = currentLatLng.longitude;
```

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```